# Rails - form_for how to keep in same line?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms

For my form below, how would I prevent the form from skipping to the next line? I have taken a look at bootstrap class "form-inline" and did not seem to work as it disabled my form.

```
Hello World!
<%= form_for(current_user.likes.build(blog_id: blog.id)) do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :blog_id %></div>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

This results in:

```
Hello World!
<Submit Button>
```

**Question: How do I make it come in one row so it is as follows:**

```
Hello World!<Submit Button>
```

Comment: Why not just using a `float: left` or `float: right`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make both your text and `form` inline or, as commented by Sparda, use `float: left` or`float: right`.

This is a trivial css thing :)